# NSDecimalNumber doubleValue incorrect for digit 7

Tags: objective-c, double, nsdecimalnumber

How can I store '0.07' value except NSDecimalNumber? I mean I can't using NSDecimalNumber because when I'm using `doubleValue` function, `decimal 0.07` becomes `0.0699999... double` or something else, but never `0.07 double` :)

Example from debugger:

```
(lldb) po [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:.07]
0.07000000000000001024

(lldb) po [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:(double).07]
0.07000000000000001024

(lldb) po [[[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:7] decimalNumberByDividingBy:[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:100]] doubleValue]
0.069999999999999993

(lldb) po 0.07
0.070000000000000007

(lldb) po (double)0.07
0.070000000000000007
```

The only way to store 0.07 is NSDecimalNumber, but it's inconvenient:

```
(lldb) po [[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:7] decimalNumberByDividingBy:[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:100]]
0.07
```

Comment: Try creating your `NSDecimalNumber` from the string `@"0.07"`.

Comment: there's no problem to create NSDecimalNumber, problem is to take double from decimal....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: yap, this is it, thank you

Comment: Also, if you need decimals down to only 2 digits, it is often good practice to use integers.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: @anoop4real Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken